# The customize scroll bar with jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, scroll

i tried a lot of customize scroll bar (like tiny scroll bar, js scroll pane etc.), but they didn't work with jquery ui tabs.. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of tiny scroll bar .please check the functionality

http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/xQSxJ/

or may be you just want to attach scroll bar to tabs in that case check here

http://jsfiddle.net/bSdbG/3/

the css

```
.container{
    width: 600px;
}
.panel{
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

the html

```
<div class='main'>
    <div id="tabs" class='container'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" class='panel'>
            <p>tab1 text...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" class='panel'>
            <p>tab2 text...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry it s not good idea, i want to customize scrool bar and i want use to together with jquery ui tabs..

Comment: Thats exactly what the second fiddle is about ;)

Comment: i don't want to use css, i know css (overflow : scroll) , i want to use customize scroll bar with jquery ui tabs. i used tiny scroll bar with ui tabs.. but javascript files overlap together... could i explain?? !!!!